# ¿Cómo enumerar lista en Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

La idea es **enumerar de forma consecutiva** las filas de la tabla, he estado haciendo varias pruebas y leyendo la documentación, pero no he conseguido dar con la solución.

Os dejo un ejemplo funcional básico, a ver si me podéis orientar.

Gracias de antemano por vuestro tiempo.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#tabla',
  
  data: {
    lista: {
            "2":{"nombre":"Paco",},
            "7":{"nombre":"Pedro",}
            },
  },


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>

Ejemplo:
<table id="tabla" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Número</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in lista">
      <td>X</td>
      <td>{{ item.nombre }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<hr>

Resultado esperado:
<table id="tabla" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Número</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Paco</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Pedro</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tus datos ya contienen un índice, por lo que debes separar el diccionario para que Vue.js pueda identificar sus partes que son los elementos del diccionario identificados en la variable `items`; las claves del diccionario, que se almacenan en la variable `keys` y el índice con base 0 en la variable `index`.

> #### Nota

Si tu data no tuviera un índice podrías usar `(items, index)`.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#tabla',
  data: {
    lista: {
      "2": {"nombre": "Paco"},
      "7": {"nombre": "Pedro"}
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table id="tabla" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Número</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, key, index) in lista">
      <td><code>index:</code> {{ index + 1 }}</td>
      <td><code>clave:</code> {{ key }} - <code>item: </code> {{ item.nombre }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Al índice le agrego un 1, para que cumpla con el resultado esperado. Y el enlace a la documentación: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-v-for